# OpenCV Crop Hough Circles Python not working

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour

[image: Please Refer this Image for the post below]
Hello there,
I am trying to build analog gauge reader by using OpenCV with Python. I have used Hough Circles to reduce coding. Code is reproduced below :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('gauge.jpg', 0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

height,width = img.shape
mask = np.zeros((height,width), np.uint8)

counter = 0

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=200,param2=100,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)

    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

    # Draw on mask
    cv2.circle(mask,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(255,255,255),-1)
    masked_data = cv2.bitwise_and(cimg, cimg, mask=mask)    

    # Apply Threshold
    _,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    # Find Contour
    cnt = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]

    #print len(contours)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt[0])

    # Crop masked_data
    crop = masked_data[y:y+h,x:x+w]

    # Write Files
    cv2.imwrite("output/crop"+str(counter)+".jpg", crop)

    counter +=1

print counter

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.imwrite("output/circled_img.jpg", cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My Questions are as below :

1. I am not getting individual Dials but in each image "crop0.jpg" has 1 but "crop1.jpg" has 2, "crop3.jpg" has 4. What I NEED is individual Circles in individual files where I can then run batch Template Matching Algo.
2. Total Result is 5 in counter which you may please note.

Comment: You might want to smooth the image before finding the circles with _HoughCircles_. Additionally, since the circles are more or less the same size, you can also try setting different values for _minRadius_ and _maxRadius_

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are doing overtime here. In this line

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20, param1=200,param2=100,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
```

you actually find the circles you are looking for but for some reason you try to find them again in the loop that follows.

You can simply get the cropped images by using the coordinates you get. Since each circle has a center and a radius you can get a bounding box which includes your circle and then (potentially) apply a mask to it.
Something like that will work I guess:

```
for c in circles[0, :]:
    c = c.astype(int)
    # get the actual cropped images here
    crop = img_copy[c[1]-c[2]:c[1]+c[2], c[0]-c[2]:c[0]+c[2]]
    # create a mask and add each circle in it
    mask = np.zeros(crop.shape)
    mask = cv2.circle(mask, (c[2], c[2]), c[2], (255, 255, 255), -1)
    final_im = mask * crop
```

just add this before to have a copy of your image before filtering it:

```
img = cv2.imread('/home/gorfanidis/misc/gauge2.jpg', 0)
img_copy = img.copy()  # <- add this to have a copy of your original image
```

Edit:

if for some reason you don't get results (return type is `None`) or get zeros results (center and radius is `0`) then you can check for either case:

```
if circles is not None:  # checks that something actually was returned
    for c in circles[0, :]:
        c = c.astype(int)
        if not c[2]:  # just checks that radius is not zero to proceed
            continue
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am getting "final_im = mask * crop" <----- Unsupported Operand type(s) for * : 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: This means that you are probably getting no circles as results I guess. Check this before

Comment: [[174 173 171 ..., 164 170 175]
 [172 172 171 ..., 164 167 174]
 [170 170 172 ..., 169 164 169]
 ...,
 [159 159 158 ..., 156 157 158]
 [157 157 157 ..., 156 156 157]
 [157 157 156 ..., 151 151 152]]
[[172 168 167 ..., 168 170 166]
 [175 167 167 ..., 166 168 165]
 [174 168 167 ..., 159 155 164]
 ...,

Comment: print of crop results 5 sets as mentioned above

Comment: c = i.astype(int)
    # get the actual cropped images here
    crop = img_copy[c[1]-c[2]:c[1]+c[2], c[0]-c[2]:c[0]+c[2]]
    print crop
 # create a mask and add each circle in it
    mask = np.zeros(crop.shape)
    mask = cv2.circle(mask, (c[2], c[2]), c[2], (255, 255, 255), -1)
    final_im = mask * crop

Comment: You are getting a `NoneType`. Check where and why this is happening. At my side the code seems to work

Comment: noneType is "mask", please see, you code i have pasted after "# Draw on Mask" and I have replaced "c = c.astype(int)" by "c = i.astype(int)" since my loop starts with "for i in circles[0,:]:"

Comment: and Link to code file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TZYVNmDSpppCwd8olX60PGXDAJih7mbj

Comment: Well I have python3 and some changes should be made but you code works for me (and for `gauge.jpg` also) but it does not return any circle. It return a circle with zero center and radius in fact.

Comment: what do you suggest, since I got circles with my original code, what changes should i do in loop to get individual pieces?